# Click on Vimeo to open in default browser - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, video, vimeo

I'm getting from JSON HTML text. In this HTML I got embedded vimeo video. So I want when user click on that video, to open default web browser and play that video in browser. I can open browser with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I don't know when to use this code. How can I get when user click on video to use the intent

Answer (score 0):

you can create a subclass of `WebViewClient` like this:

```
    public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              if(url.contains("your url")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
              } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoURL));
                startActivity(intent);
              }
              return true;
            }
        }
```

And set the webview client like this:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```